# Python sending AMF

Tags: python, amf, pyamf

I'm Learning Python And for one of my project I need to POST data to server which uses AMF messaging.

Captured headers looks like this:

```
POST (info hided)/amfgateway.php HTTP/1.1
Host: (info hided)
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 52
Origin: (info hided)
X-Requested-With: ShockwaveFlash/16.0.0.235
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-amf
Accept: */*
Referer: (info hided)
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: lt,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6,ru;q=0.4,pl;q=0.2
Cookie: (info hided)

 bcAmfService.addFriend /1   
    Aa$
```

And it's not a problem for me to POST headers but how do I format data that is sended to server:

[image]

I know there is a PyAmf library and I looked at documentation but it's very abstract and for beginner like me it's hard to put pieces together in one code.

**So how do I format this data in Python?**